# Surrounding specific HTML text with specific color

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have the a `Status` parameter for my HTML table which could take values such as :

- SUCCESS
- FAILURE
- IN PROGRESS

I want to surround the text with a specific color depending on the value it takes. I am working with Angular 4 (HTML and TypeScript).

Any pointers to solve this problem?

Comment: Define styles in a class for each status and toggle that class using `ngClass`. Example, `[ngClass]="{'success': status === 'SUCCESS', 'failure': status === 'FAILURE', 'in-progress': status === 'IN PROGRESS'}"`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "surround the text with a specific color"?  Text stroke?  Shadow?  Background?  Border around the text element?  What does your HTML look like right now?

Comment: @Brad Background precisely.

Comment: @AbhijeetMohanty `background: #f7f;`

Comment: @Brad Yes I know that, what my question is how do I vary background color depending on the content of the text.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I did not test this but hope this helps:

```
[ngStyle]="{'background-color':status === 'SUCCESS' ? 'green' : status === 'FAILURE' ? 'red' : 'blue'}
```

Comment: Please note that original author is using angular 4, your solution is for angularjs.

Comment: Yes I am using Angular 4.@Szarik

Comment: Oh! Sorry I missed that, So you can prefer this link to understand NgStyle and NgClass 
https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/built-in-directives/ngstyle-and-ngclass/

Above link for Angular 5 but it supports 4 , just sent for update

Comment: update your answer

Comment: @D.Pareek The link helped me. Could you put it up as an answer so it helps others. People are anyways hell bent on downvoting this question.